# Could NOT find combined_robot_hw (missing: combined_robot_hw_DIR)

Tags: ros, arm-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I tried cloning the repository following the instruction on the master branch (https://github.com/xArm-Developer/xarm_ros), however while doing catkin_make I am getting the following error, please help me through this. I feel like something is wrong with the controller package on their github.

````
```
-- Could NOT find combined_robot_hw (missing: combined_robot_hw_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'combined_robot_hw'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "combined_robot_hw"
  with any of the following names:

    combined_robot_hwConfig.cmake
    combined_robot_hw-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "combined_robot_hw" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "combined_robot_hw_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "combined_robot_hw" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  xarm_ros/xarm_controller/CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/akumar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/akumar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

```
````

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409007/could-not-find-combined_robot_hw-(missing:-combined_robot_hw_dir)/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-11-05**:\

> I feel like something is wrong with the controller package on their github.

let's not jump to conclusions too quick.

Did you follow the steps in the [Install other dependent packages](https://github.com/xArm-Developer/xarm_ros/tree/9d5f61e058e30bcabc965b78587eba4d3759fbc9#43-install-other-dependent-packages) section of the readme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @gvdhoorn has pointed out, it seems that you have not installed dependencies. Please follow the [documentation](https://github.com/xArm-Developer/xarm_ros/tree/9d5f61e058e30bcabc965b78587eba4d3759fbc9#43-install-other-dependent-packages) carefully.

For the error mentioned above, the `combined-robot-hw` package can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-combined-robot-hw
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0